# PDF of fx(x) to CDF Fy(y)

Tags: statistics

I'm following some free online courses in order to prepare for grad school a few years down the road, but I'm finding them to be difficult to follow. I feel like this will be an easy question though.

**Given pdf density fx(x) = 2x, for 0 <= x <=1, 0 otherwise

Find the CDF function Fy(y) for y = 3x-1.**

I know that to get the CDF of fx(x) from the PDF I integrate over the range 0 to 1 but how do I use the CDF or PDF for X to get the CDF function Fy(y) for y?

Thank you.

Comment: (-1) for the unreadability.

Comment: If this is really how this online course writes things up, leave the course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should find that $P(X\leq x)=x^2$. Then for $-1 \leq y \leq 2$,

$$P(Y\leq y) = P(3X-1 \leq y) = P(X \leq \tfrac{y+1}{3}),$$

so the CDF of $Y$ is

$$F_{Y}(y) = \left(\frac{y+1}{3}\right)^2.$$

Comment: Thanks, Lythia. It's much more clear to me now!

Comment: You're welcome Joe.